# Weekly newsletters are not customizable

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

How about making weekly newsletters customizable?
What about those two ideas:

- send only one newsletter with all the subscriptions in it. I get 20 mails/week. I'd be happy if I got just one.
- define how often to get them: each week, each other week, once a month, once a semester, once a year.

What do you think?

Comment: What would be the use of an annual newsletter? Most of the questions would be dead.

Comment: I always learn a lot. Do you think that travelling questions/advices will be useless in one year? This may apply to a lot of other subjects as well, but maybe not to state of the art technology. Anyway you're right, one year may be too much, but you got the big picture anyway... that was the most important to me :)