# Don't include hidden tags in weekly newsletters

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

Related to [*Customized newsletters*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184891/131197) and [*Weekly newsletters are not customizable*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110834/131197) - why do so many entries in the newsletters I get include questions for tags I explicitly hide?

For example, in the Board & Card Games Weekly, there's all kinds of [magic-the-gathering](/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) questions hilit - a tag I hide on BoardGames.SE.

Including questions related to hidden tags only serves to clutter-up the newsletter and my inbox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can newsletters take into account a user's ignored tags on that site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169705/131197)

Comment: Third paragraph of the linked "... take into account the user's ... ignored tags for that site."